# How to export HTML User input to xls

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to export user input to xls. While doing research on how to do it, I managed to find example code which is supposed to export html input to xls. However when I try and execute the code, on pressing the export button, nothing happens. Can someone please have a look at the code and point out the mistake

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
    padding : 10px;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:grey;
    color: white;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
input {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="dvData">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column One</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Three</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row1 Col1</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2 Col1</td>
            <td>row2 Col2</td>
            <td>row2 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row3 Col1</td>
            <td>row3 Col2</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to use this jQuery library https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel

Comment: Later on you should try a better example site, that one's pretty awful. Right now you should start with a tutorial on JavaScript so you can get an idea of how JavaScript gets into the browser and gets run. You're obviously way in over your head.